# Printf formatting for decimal places

Tags: java

I have the following code and my output is working but I don't know how to use the printf to make this output (66.67%) instead of 66.66666666666667%, just for an example. Any help is appreciated!

```
public static void evenNumbers(Scanner input) 
{
     int numNums = 0;
     int numEvens = 0;
     int sum = 0;

 while (input.hasNextInt()) 
  {
     int number = input.nextInt();
      numNums++;
     sum += number;
   if (number % 2 == 0) 
   {
        numEvens++;
   }
  }
     System.out.println(numNums + " numbers, sum = " + sum);
     System.out.println(numEvens + " evens " + (100.0* numEvens / numNums + "%"));



}
```

Thank you

Comment: Use [printf](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/csc2010/f13/assignments/h4/printf.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the printf modifier `%.2f` to get only two decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and `%.2f`:

```
String.format("%d evens %.2f%%", numEvens, 100.0 * numEvens / numNums);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I got it to this now apparently I need it to say 8 evens (66.67%), where would it be good to stick in the parentheses?          System.out.printf("%d evens %.2f%%", numEvens, 100.0 * numEvens / numNums);

Comment: You would write `"%d evens (%.2f%%)"`. Maybe [this article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html) helps you understand string formatting in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round on the answer before you print it:

```
     System.out.println(numEvens + " evens " + Math.round((100.0* numEvens / numNums)*100)/100.0d + "%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `printf` here. Instead, use `MessageFormat` or `DecimalFormat.getPercentInstance()`.

```
String format = "{numbers: {0, number, integer}," +
                " sum: {1, number,  integer}\n" +
                "evens: {2, number, integer}," +
                " {3, number, percent}"
String message = MessageFormat.format(format,
    new Object[]{numNums, sum, numEvens, ((double) numEvens)/ numNums)});
System.out.println(message);
```